# Store date from calendar picker into SQL Server using SqlTransaction - Visual studio 2015/C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

For some reason, I can't seem to pass the value from a datepicker into my SQL transaction and store it in the database. When I tested it using 'hard coded' data, it worked fine. But now when I try pass a date from the calendar picker, it bombs out and throws a syntax error.

Code to be executed on button click:

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sampConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procinsert", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datesaved", Calendar1.SelectedDate);
```

SQL Server stored procedure that handles the insert:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procinsert]
    @name varchar(100), 
    @email varchar(320), 
    @datesaved date     
AS
begin
begin transaction 
  begin try
      insert into dataentry (name, email, dateadded) 
      values(@name, @email, @datesaved) 
  end try
  begin catch
    select ERROR_MESSAGE(),ERROR_SEVERITY()
    if @@trancount >0 
      rollback transaction 
  end catch 

  if @@Trancount >0
    commit transaction
  end
```

For the life of me, I can't work out why I'm getting the syntax error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxgt6.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score -1):

Exacly what error you're getting? It's hard to tell without that info but first thing that can be wrong is that Calendar1.SelectedDate gives you full DateTime object (date with time) and in your SQL procedure you're expecting pure DATE type.

Either try passing only Date part:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datesaved", Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("g"));
```

Or change parameter type in your procedure:

```
@datesaved datetime2
```